# How to efficiently parse a maximum of two depths with Json.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, json, mono, json.net

Given Json input like the following:

```
{
    "Group A": {
        "Prop A": 42,
        "Prop B": true,
        "Prop C": [ "Hello", "World!" ]
    },
    "Group B": {
        "Prop A": 72
    }
}
```

I would like to populate the following data structure:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Groups;
```

Such that the following statement would be true (differences in whitespace are not important):

```
Groups["Group A"]["Prop C"] == "[\"Hello\",\"World!\"]"
```

### Inefficient Solution:

The following *seems* to solve this problem, but it is quite inefficient since it incurs unnecessary intermediary serialization:

```
Groups = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
foreach (var jsonGroup in JObject.Parse(jsonText)) {
    var group = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Groups[jsonGroup.Key] = group;

    foreach (var jsonProperty in jsonGroup.Value.Children<JProperty>())
        group[jsonProperty.Name] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonProperty.Value);
}
```

Sadly `JProperty.Value.ToString()` seems to return odd values, for instance `"False"` instead of `"false"`.

Comment: Would you consider using classes instead of serializing it into a Dictionary?

Comment: @JWLim classes are fine provided that the access is `obj[groupName][propertyName] == nestedJsonTextWhichMustBeDeserializedLater`

Comment: On second glance, classes are probably more trouble than they're worth. You can just deserialize it into a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>` right now with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`, and then call `obj[groupName][propertyName].ToString()` when required.

Comment: consider using your approach but instead of storing the raw string, store the Children in the dictionary and only create the string as needed. You still have to parse the whole thing to really break it down, and this way you do it once. This of course assumes that you only need random access and not going to have to read the whole thing.

Comment: @JWLim But `.ToString()` doesn't produce valid JSON for boolean values? Am I doing something wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the intended behaviour of `JValue.ToString()` is to return the enclosed value as a string rather than encode to JSON. Instead `JValue.ToString(IFormatProvider)` should be used to produce a valid JSON encoded string.

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/266

However, in my particular case it seems to make better sense to retain the Json.NET representation since this avoids reparsing the same JSON content multiple times:

```
Groups = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, JToken>>();
foreach (var jsonGroup in JObject.Parse(jsonText)) {
    var group = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
    Groups[jsonGroup.Key] = group;

    foreach (var jsonProperty in jsonGroup.Value.Children<JProperty>())
        group[jsonProperty.Name] = jsonProperty.Value;
}
```

And then, instead of parsing these sub-structures with `JObject.Parse` I can use `JToken.ToObject<T>` to convert them into the desired representation:

```
bool myValue = Groups["Group A"]["Prop B"].ToObject<bool>();
```